# Supertest/mocha Error: global leak detected: path

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js

So I'm trying to write tests for my REST API (built on top of Express and Mongoose), but I have run into some trouble.

I have followed a lot of examples and tutorials, which suggest that my solution below should work, but it isn't - I am getting a `Error: global leak detected: path`

It seems that the line that is causing it is `.post( '/api/invoices' )` - but I cannot figure out why.

```
var app = require("../app").app,
    request = require("supertest");

describe("Invoice API", function() {

    it( "GET /api/invoices should return 200", function (done) {
        request(app)
            .get( '/api/invoices' )
            .expect( 200, done );
    });

    it( "GET /api/invoices/_wrong_id should return 500", function (done) {
        request(app)
            .get( '/api/invoices/_wrong_id' )
            .expect( 500, done );
    });

    it( "POST /api/invoices should return 200", function (done) {
        request(app)
            .post( '/api/invoices' )
            .set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' )
            .send( { number: "200" } )
            .expect( 200, done );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that somewhere in your code you're missing your `var` declaration. Mocha is smart enough to detect this in your entire project, not just your test files.

As in, you're probably doing this:

```
path = require('path');
```

instead of

```
var path = require('path');
```

Or maybe even...

```
var fs = require('fs')     //<--- notice the missing comma
    path = require('path');
```

When you don't declare your variables they get attached to the global scope. In Node.js, that's `global` and in the browser that's `window`.

Comment: Yep! That indeed was the issue, although it wasn't so obvious. I had a `for .. in` loop like this: `for (path in object) ...` and the issue was that I hadn't declared `var path` before the loop. Thanks!